# How to add input type="number" in Laravel Blade template?

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want to make an input field where the user can only enter a number. In HTML5, we can use `<input type="number">`. How do I do this in blade?

I tried this:

```
{!! Form::number('amount', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
```

Answer (score 9):

I could search and code it. Since there was no direct answer, I thought to post the working code below:

```
{!! Form::input('number', 'amount', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use either `Form::input()` method or `Form::number()` method to achieve your goal.

**Form::input() method**

This method takes 4 arguments.

1. $type - (required) The first argument specifies the type of input. Values such as "text", "number", "password", "file", etc. are accepted.
2. $name - (required) The second argument is name.
3. $value - (optional) The third argument is the value for the input field.
4. $options - (optional) The fourth argument is an array of additional field attributes. The array can be populated with items having keys such as "id", "size", or "class".

*Example:*

```
{{ Form::input('number', 'name') }}
{{ Form::input('number', 'name', 'value', ['class' => 'number', 'id' => 'numberField']) }}

//both example will create elements like this

<input name="name" type="number" value="value">
<input name="name" type="number" value="value" class="number" id="numberField">
```

**Form::number() method**

This method takes 3 arguments.

1. $name - (required) The first argument is name.
2. $value - (optional) The second argument is the value for the input field.
3. $options - (optional) The third argument is an array of additional field attributes. The array can be populated with items having keys such as "id", "size", or "class".

*Example:*

```
Form::number('name')
Form::number('name', null, ['class' => 'number', 'id' => 'numberField'])

//both example will create elements like this

<input name="name" type="number">
<input name="name" type="number" class="number" id="numberField">
```

> **Tips:** if you want to use `$options` and don't want to assign any default value, use `null` at the `$value` argument.

Answer (score 1):

**Input field with minimum value of 0.**

```
{!! Form::number('count', $value = '' , ['min' => '0' ,'class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'number_count','required']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{!!  Form::input('number', 'weight', null, ['id' => 'weight', 'class' => 'form-control', 'min' => 1, 'max' => 9999, 'required' => 'required']) !!}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use javascript:

```
function isNumberKey(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

and in your html:

```
<input name="input_name" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">
```